# Handling @nuxt/apollo response 400 from graph query

Tags: javascript, graphql, vuejs3, apollo, nuxtjs3

I use @nuxt/apollo in my nuxt3 app for handling graph and in my index.vue I do:

```js
try {
  const { result } = useQuery(query, variables)
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error', e)
}
```

It works and fetch my data but when I return 400 from graph it's crashing entire app with this screen (screenshot). How do I handle the error? It's okey that graph sometimes return 400, I don't want entire app to crash

[image]